# How to fix 'Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13]' in terminal mac

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, permission-denied, oserror

I'm trying to deploy an app that I wrote in python 3.9 using kivy to ios/xcode. I'm following a set of instructions off this website:

[kivy-ios 1.2.1](https://pypi.org/project/kivy-ios/)

(I have also tried all other websites and instructions, this is just one of them).  When I run any version of the command: sudo python3 ./toolchain.py build kivy (i've also tried variations like toolchain build python3 kivy, etc) in terminal it tells me this:

```
OSError: [Errno socket error] [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)
```

I found a solution to this online, which is going to my Python 3.9 folder in Applications and clicking on Install Certificates.command folder. This opens a new terminal tab and I get this message:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/__init__.py'
Consider using the--user option or check the permissions.
```

I've tried all manners of trying to solve this error. I've run

```
sudo chown ananya /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/__init__.py
```

I've gone into 'get info' and changed the permissions, but I keep on getting this error. Do you have any idea how to help me?

Comment: Try `pip3 install certifi` in your terminal. If that still give you permission denied, try `pip3 install certifi --user`

Comment: Also it's not a good idea to change permissions on anything in `/Library/`.

Comment: I tried doing that and it still didn't work, do you have any other suggestions?